# Joomla 3.4 installation issue

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying a Joomla 3 quickstart package. I uploaded all the files to the server and went through the 4 installation steps (Configuration,Database,FTP,Overview). I have selected "Default English" for language and I installed the sample data. After clicking the Install button Joomla creates the tables in db, and then stops and goes back to the Overview section without creating the configuration.php file and without creating some tables.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Anyone can help me to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked any of your logs such as php_error.log?

Comment: Problem solved. One of .xml files did not exist and this was a error cause. The error log was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely running into a file permission issue. Check to see whether Apache can write files to your filesystem. Also check that you have enough space on your server.

A final thing to consider is to check whether you have some PHP configuration issues (such as session issues).